# How to get multiple buttons from a single tableViewcell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button, tags

I am making a quiz in a `tableView` that has 4 Buttons (options), I tagged them on a story board like 201,202,203,204 and got all of them successfully in `tableView` methods. But after adding targets to buttons, I am not able to get particular buttons in `buttonClicked` method.

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return questions.count }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    (cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UILabel).text = "Q : " + (questions[indexPath.row].objectForKey("MocQuestion")! as? String)!
    (cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UILabel).font = themeFont
    (cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UILabel).text = questions[indexPath.row].objectForKey("Op1")! as? String
    (cell.viewWithTag(102) as! UILabel).text = questions[indexPath.row].objectForKey("Op2")! as? String
    (cell.viewWithTag(103) as! UILabel).text = questions[indexPath.row].objectForKey("Op3")! as? String
    (cell.viewWithTag(104) as! UILabel).text = questions[indexPath.row].objectForKey("Op4")! as? String

    let btn1 = (cell.viewWithTag(201) as! UIButton)
    let btn2 = (cell.viewWithTag(202) as! UIButton)
    let btn3 = (cell.viewWithTag(203) as! UIButton)
    let btn4 = (cell.viewWithTag(204) as! UIButton)


//        btn1.tag = indexPath.row * 100 + 0
//        btn1.tag = indexPath.row * 100 + 1
//        btn1.tag = indexPath.row * 100 + 2
//        btn1.tag = indexPath.row * 100 + 3


    btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Quiz.buttonClicked(_:)),forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Quiz.buttonClicked(_:)),forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    btn3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Quiz.buttonClicked(_:)),forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    btn4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Quiz.buttonClicked(_:)),forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
    let tag = sender.tag
    print(tag)
}
```

[image]

Comment: so what is the issue? your tag should print perfact. you should have problem to identify correct row!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `indexPath` to access the questions `Array` then you can try like this.

```
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    let center = sender.center
    let point = sender.superview!.convertPoint(center, toView:self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
    //Now you have tag of button check for that
    if (sender.tag == 201) {
        print("Option A")
    }
    else if (sender.tag == 202) {
        print("Option B")
    }
    else if (sender.tag == 203) {
        print("Option C")
    }
    else {
        print("Option D")
    }
    print(question[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: but Option A for which question? plus i also need to get other 3 buttons to make changes. but for particular question.

Comment: for `(questions[indexPath.row].objectForKey("MocQuestion")` this question i think!!

Comment: Read my answer carefully it will give you indexPath, from that you can get the question from which button is tap. Also no need to change the tag in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 2):

In **swift 3** You can try bellow like

1. My  table cell class

   ```
   class Custom_Cell: UITableViewCell {    

     @IBOutlet weak var ButtonA: UIButton!
     @IBOutlet weak var ButtonB: UIButton!
     @IBOutlet weak var ButtonC: UIButton!

    }
   ```
2. Set Tag in table view

   ```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Custom_Cell;



      cell.ButtonA.tag = indexPath.row;
      cell.ButtonB.tag = indexPath.row;
      cell.ButtonA.tag = indexPath.row;

       //Add Action Methods to UIButtons
        cell.ButtonA.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonAAction), for: .touchUpInside)
       cell.ButtonB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonBAction), for: .touchUpInside)
       cell.ButtonA.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonCAction), for: .touchUpInside)

      return cell;
   }
   ```
3. Button Action will look like ..

   ```
   func ButtonAAction(_ sender: Any)  {
      //Get Button cell position.
      let ButtonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableView)
      let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: ButtonPosition)
      if indexPath != nil {


          print("Cell indexPath: \(indexPath?.row)")
       }
     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get every ques separate button `click event` you can pass the unique ID as postfix or prefix e.g 20101 or 01201 of every ques as a tag of button instead of hard-coded. Then get the tag and extract ques id first now proceed for examination as per ques.