# Interactive header with buttons of tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, callback

I have a tableView which have one two cells.

1. first for section header having 3 buttons, acting as a check box,and
2. second cell with simple labels to populate the data.

Now what I want is to update the tableView's second cells data with a section header like shown in screenshot below. But I'm unable to get the clickable action for these buttons on the same header.

What I tried so far is:

1. first I used tapReconizer for all three of them, it was working but it was not changing the image of the button (which is imp, as through image it is acting like a checkbox)
2. then I made the action outlet for all three now they are working as in but I'm unable to update data from the cell's custom class, below is the code

   ```
   class SavedCallHeader : UITableViewCell{
   var checkBox_PlannedisOn:Bool = false
   var checkBox_BothisOn:Bool = true
   var checkBox_unPlannedisOn:Bool = false
     let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

   @IBOutlet weak var PlannedBoxBtn: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var BothBoxBtn: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var unPlannedBoxBtn: UIButton!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
   }


   @IBAction func PlannedCheckBox(_ sender: UIButton) {
       if checkBox_PlannedisOn == false {
           self.PlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
           checkBox_PlannedisOn = true
           print("i'm finally here proper click!")

        // self.fetchData() // wont' work here as it is in the main VC Class
       // tableView.reloadData() // won't work here as well

       }else {
           self.PlannedBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
           print("i'm finally heress proper click!")
           checkBox_PlannedisOn = false

       }

   }
   ```

I want to update and refresh data on every time the user select/deSelect the checkBox. Below is my main code:

```
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

            let identifierHeader:String = "SavedCallHeader"

            let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifierHeader) as! SavedCallHeader



           /*  let tapPlanned = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGestureP))
             let tapBoth = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGestureB))
             let tapUnPlanned = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGestureU))
             headerCell.PlannedBoxBtn.addGestureRecognizer(tapPlanned)
             headerCell.BothBoxBtn.addGestureRecognizer(tapBoth)
             headerCell.unPlannedBoxBtn.addGestureRecognizer(tapUnPlanned)
     */
            return headerCell

        }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier:String = "savedcall_cell"

        let cell:SavedCalls_Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:identifier ) as! SavedCalls_Cell!
        if(drname.count > 0){
         //Fetching data from table view and then reload
    }
```

Comment: Dont use gesture. First make sure your button action is properly calling or not.

Comment: Use call back for update your main code

Comment: @dahiya_boy yes it is getting called properly as i mentioned, on the button click image is getting chenged. but the problem is i can't update data from that action click because it is in the custom cell's class.

Comment: @Bala how? i'm a bit new to iOS.

Comment: Use delegate to interact with your main class

Comment: @LalKrishna how? can you elaborate with a code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating callBack like this in your cell class

```
var callBackForReload : ((Bool) -> ())?

@IBAction func PlannedCheckBox(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // when you call this call back it will excute in where you acces it.
    // I pass bool value for examble. you will pass whtever datatype you want
    self.callBackForReload!(true)
}
```

The below code execute after CallBack code executed in your cell class

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let identifierHeader:String = "SavedCallHeader"

    let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifierHeader) as! SavedCallHeader

    headerCell.callBackForReload = { [weak self] (isCalled) -> Void in
        //This will call when the call back code excuted in your cell class
        // in The isCalled variable you will get the value from cell class
        // You will reload your changed value here
    }

    return headerCell

}
```

Comment: it is showing error on headerCell.contentHeight, as there is no contentHeight field!?

Comment: sorry check it now

Comment: Welcome ... :-)

Comment: I'm facing a little problem again i hope you can fix it, as mentioned 3 buttons i used your callBack three times and apply condition on isCalled, all worked well. but when it try to fetch Data and reload it, then it is not accessing the actionOutlet of two buttons,only one button is working then. i don't why only reloading the data is causing this!!

Comment: i just rechecked, it is accessing the action outlets but not changing the value of condition as well as the image.

Comment: Not getting your problem clearly ... Tell me what you exactly want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146604/discussion-between-shahtaj-khalid-and-bala).

Comment: Are you there ? i have got a problem with this one again and it's a bit urgent i'm hoping you can help me out!?

Comment: what i want is when the customer select on check box, other checkboxes should be unselected. but i unable to get this done1

Comment: If u want only one true value true, make other false.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do below things,

1. Instead of `UITableViewCell`, you have to take Button Outlets in `ViewController`.
2. When User clicked on any cell you can get on which button and cell user clicked. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289066/how-to-get-multiple-buttons-from-a-single-tableviewcell)
3. Now reload that cell/section as user clicked. [Ref](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata)

Comment: i want to achieve this through header!!

Comment: @shahtajkhalid Is these three options (planed/ unplanned/ both) is for every  cell??

Comment: it's an overall header for the tableview, yup every other cell will be updated according to these checkboxes.